# How could HashMap assurance same index when a duplicate key added with different `tab.length`?

Tags: java, android

The following piece of code is used to add an element to a HashMap (from Android 5.1.1 source tree), I'm very confused this statement:`int index = hash & (tab.length - 1);`, how could this map assurance the same index when a duplicate key added with different `tab.length`?

For example, assume that we have a new empty HashMap hMap. Firstly, we add  pair ("1","1") to it, assume `tab.length` equals 1 at this time, then we add many  pairs to this map, assume `tab.length` equals "x", now we add a duplicate  pair ("1","1") to it, notice that the `tab.length` is changed, so the index's value `int index = hash & (tab.length - 1);` may also changed.

```
 /**
 * Maps the specified key to the specified value.
 *
 * @param key
 *            the key.
 * @param value
 *            the value.
 * @return the value of any previous mapping with the specified key or
 *         {@code null} if there was no such mapping.
 */
@Override public V put(K key, V value) {
    if (key == null) {
        return putValueForNullKey(value);
    }

    int hash = Collections.secondaryHash(key);
    HashMapEntry<K, V>[] tab = table;
    int index = hash & (tab.length - 1);
    for (HashMapEntry<K, V> e = tab[index]; e != null; e = e.next) {
        if (e.hash == hash && key.equals(e.key)) {
            preModify(e);
            V oldValue = e.value;
            e.value = value;
            return oldValue;
        }
    }

    // No entry for (non-null) key is present; create one
    modCount++;
    if (size++ > threshold) {
        tab = doubleCapacity();
        index = hash & (tab.length - 1);
    }
    addNewEntry(key, value, hash, index);
    return null;
}
```

Comment: I think you need to look up "hash tables" in Wikipedia or something to see how they work.  `tab.length` is **not** the number of elements you've added.  It's a table of a fixed length that is allocated when the hash table is created.  The table size normally doesn't change when you add or remove elements.  (It's possible for the table size to change, if the implementation allows for that possibility in order to better optimize the table; but then the entire table has to be reconstructed from scratch.)

Comment: When table need to reconstruct, it will first re-computing the index of older element, so the index will follow the changes of table's length.

Answer (score 0):

When table need to reconstruct, it will first re-computing the index of older element, so the index will follow the changes of table's length.